# Incorrect values after export xml from DB for table bigint(20)

Tags: mysql, export

This below is part of my script code for export data from table to xml.

query:

```
$query = "SELECT p.id, p.slug, p.sku, p.price, p.vat_rate, p.stock, p.brand, p.ean, p.gender, 
    pd.title, pd.description 
FROM products p
INNER JOIN product_details pd ON p.id = pd.id
WHERE p.stock >= 50";
```

function:

```
function createXMLfile($productsArray){
  
   $filePath = 'googleshopping.xml';

   $dom     = new DOMDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 

   $root      = $dom->createElement('channel'); 

   for($i=0; $i<count($productsArray); $i++){ 
$productPrice     =  $productsArray[$i]['price']; 
     $price    = $dom->createElement('g:price', $productPrice.$productCurrency); 

     $product->appendChild($price); 

$root->appendChild($product);
$dom->appendChild($root); 

   $dom->save($filePath); 

 }
```

Column with price is  `bigint(20)`. The problem is, because example price in store is `47,97` but in DB this price is displayed like `4797` - and when I export this value to XML then also I get `4797` instand of `47,97`. Any solution?

Comment: *example price in store is `47,97`* ?? Where the comma is taken from? MySQL must produce a value with decimal dot.

Comment: @Akina, I just don't know where this is coming from. Please see, this is how I enter the price https://prnt.sc/hS9LnAWFG2p8 and in the store you can see the price with a comma, which is ok as in this case: 121,33. But when I open DB then I see this: 12133. And when I export this I also have 12133.

Comment: Please see screen from table price: https://prnt.sc/uotJFUGYAgS4

Comment: On website is ok: https://prnt.sc/xZAceGVKFGBh and I dont know how to "decode this" during export, and export normal price with comma

Comment: Some European languages use commas instead of dots.  Need to change the "locale".

Comment: And `BIGINT` only handles Euros, no cents.  Perhaps you want  something like `DECIMAL(11,2)`